# ios 6.1.3 : No calendar has been set

Tags: calendar, ios6.1

I am trying to save an event on a device running ios 6.1.3 however I keep getting the error 'No calendar has been set'.

I have used the requestAccessToEntity:completion: to gey user permission however the EventStore still gives error even after user allows access.

The application runs on the simulator and on devices running ios 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same problem on 6.1.3 and 6.1.4.

If you're trying to create the event in the completion block of `requestAccessToEntity:completion:`, you can't create the event in that block if you also create the `EKCalendar`.

Steps:

1. Call `requestAccessToEntity:completion:`
2. If successful, create new `EKCalendar` inside completion block
3. Outside of the completion block, create your new `EKEvent` using your new `EKCalendar` and add it